# Alternative to loading class dynamically in Java

Tags: java

I have the following method:

```
private static Class<?> classForName(final String classNameToIgnore) {
    try {
        return TypeAnyHelper.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(classNameToIgnore);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This has been flagged as potentially insecure as we are dynamically loading a class at runtime:

```
return TypeAnyHelper.class.getClassLoader().loadClass(classNameToIgnore);
```

What is the best way to implement the same functionality in this scenario without loading the classToIgnoreName dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: That depends on what you want. I do not dynamically load a class because I have no need for it. Do you have a need for it and if so: why, what need?

Comment: I want to achieve the same functionality at the method, just without loading the class dynamically. In other words, load the class "classNameToIgnore" without using the loadClass()

Comment: What is the original reason for this method?  You need to understand that before you can find a better fix

Answer (score 1):

It's the loading a class at runtime that's insecure - no matter which way you do this.

Technically, you could embed a groovy interpreter and execute runtime code that way - this might get you around the warning that you're mentioning, but you'd be open to exactly the same vulnerabilities: You're running code that potentially has not been vetted to run on a server or in the environment that you're running.

As you ask for an alternative *in this scenario*: We don't know your scenario. Some static warnings make you think twice about the technique used. If it is mandatory to use this technique, because you're implementing *that kind of software*: Ignore it, and document why you do so.

If you truly need an alternative, I'd consider this question a [x-y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/364505) and you should state your underlying business problem rather than the implementation that you already chose - because it might be the wrong choice for an implementation in the first place.